# how to input /x00 memory address in c?

Tags: c, linux, memory

I am learning format string attack from my book Hacking : Art of Exploitation.
I have this small program and this is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char text[1024];
   static int test_val = -72;

   if(argc < 2) {
      printf("Usage: %s <text to print>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
   }
   strcpy(text, argv[1]);

   printf("The right way to print user-controlled input:\n");
   printf("%s", text);


   printf("\nThe wrong way to print user-controlled input:\n");
   printf(text);

   printf("\n");

   // Debug output
   printf("[*] test_val @ 0x%016x = %d 0x%08x\n", &test_val, test_val, test_val);

   exit(0);
}
```

I want to input address to my program and print it. The address is `0x00600b98` because of little endian byte order I input `"\x98\x0b\x60\x00"`

this is my bash code :
`./fmt_vuln $(python -c 'print "\x98\x0b\x60\x00"')%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.`

But the problem is, the first address (\x00) its become null and not inputed to my address and when the memory is printed it become `25600b98`. So my question is, why this problem happen and how to input address of 00 ?

This is the output:

```
The right way to print user-controlled input:
�
 `%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.
The wrong way to print user-controlled input:
�
 `f7ff5000.f7dd7970.f7b128c0.f7fd8700.0000002b.ffffe3b8.f7ddb72d.25600b98.
[*] test_val @ 0x0000000000600b98 = -72 0xffffffb8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argv[1]` points to a character array with the contents `"\x98\x0b\x60\x00"`.  Notice this is 5 bytes: 4 plus a null character.

The following code only copies until reaching a null character, which results in only 4 bytes being copied as `argv[1][3]` is a null character.

```
strcpy(text, argv[1]);
```

Suggest adding optional 2nd parameter and calling the program with an additional parameter indicating the length.

```
size_t size = 0;
if (argc > 2) {
  long i = atol(argv[2]);
  if (i >= 0 && i < SIZE_MAX) {
    size = (size_t) i;
  }
else {
  size = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;
}
// strcpy(text, argv[1]);
memcpy(text, argv[1], size);
```

Note that the following code will still only print to first 3 characters

```
printf("%s", text);
printf(text); // UB if it contains '%'
```

BTW: Suggest doing debug output before `printf(text);` and fixing its mis-matched formats

```
// printf("[*] test_val @ 0x%016x = %d 0x%08x\n", &test_val, test_val, test_val);
printf("[*] test_val @ 0x%016x = %d 0x%08x\n", 
    (unsigned) &test_val, test_val, (unsigned) test_val);
// or
printf("[*] test_val @ %p = %d 0x%08x\n", 
    (void*) &test_val, test_val, (unsigned) test_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because null bytes (/x00), at least in C, are used to terminate a string. So, when you `printf` them, they are interpreted as the end of the string.

A great explanation on this, coupled with information on how to properly incorporate null bytes into your code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621006/how-can-a-file-contain-null-bytes).

I hope this helps.